# Best way for acquiring an element's height

Tags: c#, wpf

The code gets the desired height for an element given a Datatemplate and the object to be bound to content.  However, this is really slow.  Does anyone have an alternative, or an idea how to optimize this code.

```
public static Double GetDesiredHeight(Object content, DataTemplate  dataTemplate)
{
        try
        {
            ContentPresenter element = new ContentPresenter
            {
                Content = content,
                ContentTemplate = dataTemplate,
            };

            element.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            var result = element.DesiredSize.Height;
            element.ContentTemplate = null;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using `ActualHeight` property instead of `Height` property?

try to change this line:

```
var result = element.DesiredSize.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: Desired size is of type `System.Windows.Size`. It doesn't have an ActualHeight property.  The code works and returns the correct value. However, creating the element using datatemplate and calling measure prior to render is slow.  I'm using this to dynamically paginate templated elements.  I suppose I could paginate after the layout process which eliminates the need for me to calculate the element's dimension manually.